# How to set a full screen popup background in Swift

Tags: swift, popup

I am a beginner in iOS development.

I  followed this tutorial https://github.com/nrlnishan/ViewPager-Swift to implement a viewPager in my application.

Then I followed https://github.com/nbyn/MWAPopup/blob/master/README.md to implement a popup in the first view of the popup.

But the popup background doesn't appear as full screen.

This screenshot may explain more my problem.

[image: Screenshot]

Please help me.

Comment: Try

`popup?.show(vc: self.navigationController!)`

instead of

`popup?.show(vc: self)`

Comment: Thank you very much ,  you give me a perfect solution to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the popup on the wrong UIViewController. `show` method shows the popup inside the UIViewController that is passed in as a parameter.

Also when using someones else's GitHub code or library, always look for the number of the stars for the repository since the most quality solutions are recognized by the community, especially solutions to the popular problems like popups. Try something like this https://github.com/Orderella/PopupDialog

Comment: Thanks a lot for  your help and the useful link that you post.